# How to generate a random number in a given range with uniform probability

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms, random-number-generator

I have used programming languages which generate a random number in a given range.

Let's say we have a range of 1 to 10 each number has the probability of 1/10 to get selected. What is the criteria on the basis of which a random number is selected with uniform probability by a programming language.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Are you asking how to convert the random bits generated by a PRNG to a uniform number from 1 to 10?

Comment: @Yuval_Filmus I think he is asking how to prove the uniformity of a generator.